# Java Sort Data From A File Using Arrays

Tags: java

I have to write a method that reads the file **integers.txt** and return an array of integers. I have to convert each line of data from text to an integer.

However, I cannot figure out why I am getting an error when I try to assign the array x to the integers within the file and when I convert the data to integers. I am also getting an error with my return statement.

```
public static int[] processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    double number;
    double average;
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("integers.txt")));
    String line;
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        number = Int.parseInt(line);
        int[] x = (number);
        inputReader.close();
    }
    return int[] x;
}
```

Comment: int[n]=number, and n need to be a int (the position)... in your code.., plus your field number switch from double to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You are using `return int[] x;` instead of simply `return x;`
2. `x` is only assigned inside the while, so you can't return it outside
3. `x = (number);` isn't a correct method for adding a value to the array
4. The `int[] x;` is never initialized
5. You use `double number` at the top of the method, but then assign it with an `int` here: `number = Int.parseInt(line);`

My suggestions is to use this instead, which will give an `ArrayList<int>` as output.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("integers.txt")));
    String line;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        int number = Int.parseInt(line);
        list.add(number);
    }
    inputReader.close();
    return list;
}
```

If you really need an `int[]` instead, you'll have to give it a size first like this: `int[] x = new int[size_here];` For example:

```
public static int[] processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("integers.txt")));
    String line;
    int[] array = new int[100]; // Example size of 100
    int index = 0;
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        int number = Int.parseInt(line);
        array[index++] = number;
    }
    inputReader.close();
    return array;
}
```

And if you need an `int[]` instead, AND don't know the size beforehand, try this instead:

```
public static int[] processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("integers.txt")));
    String line;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        int number = Int.parseInt(line);
        list.add(number);
    }
    inputReader.close();
    return convertIntegers(list);
}

public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's `Integer.parseInt()`

```
 number = Int.parseInt(line);
        int[] x = (number);
```

`number` will contain a single `int` not an array of ints. so this `int[] x = (number);` assignment is wrong.

`return int[] x;` this is also invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. To answer your question, you can't assign an int to an int array. Next, unless you entered your code incorrectly, you are closing the inputReader inside the while loop that is doing the reading. Also, you are returning int[] x. That is wrong. Return x.